# Query Filter based on condition

Tags: sql, sql-server-2019

I have this query (SQL Server 2019) and I actually wanted to add a filter to it to show only items where `IssueStatusID` = 1 (This column is based on int Data Type)
Can anyone help with this or point me in the right direction?

```
SELECT ID, 
STRING_AGG(TRY_CONVERT(varchar, Issue#, 101)  + ': ' + Notes + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + CHAR(13), CHAR(10)) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY Issue# DESC) AS IssueNotes 
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT 
    ac4.ID, 
    nd.Notes, 
    nd.Issue#,
    nd.IssueStatusID

FROM dbo.IssueTracking AS nd
    INNER JOIN dbo.StatusUpdates AS ac4 ON ac4.ID = nd.ReleaseTrackerID) AS vNotes
GROUP BY ID;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the WHERE clause as shown below.   The WHERE clause limits the data being returned.

```
SELECT ID, 
STRING_AGG(TRY_CONVERT(varchar, Issue#, 101)  + ': ' + Notes + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + CHAR(13), CHAR(10)) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY Issue# DESC) AS IssueNotes 
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT 
    ac4.ID, 
    nd.Notes, 
    nd.Issue#,
    nd.IssueStatusID

FROM dbo.IssueTracking AS nd
    INNER JOIN dbo.StatusUpdates AS ac4 ON ac4.ID = nd.ReleaseTrackerID
    WHERE nd.IssueStatusID = 1
) AS vNotes
GROUP BY ID;
```